# Can anyone help in fixing this constant "ModuleNotFoundError" on Google Colaboratory?

Tags: python, runtime-error, google-colaboratory, astronomy, modulenotfounderror

here is my code to import some python libraries:

```
from radmc3dPy import *
from radmc3dPy.image import *
from radmc3dPy.analyze import *
from radmc3dPy.natconst import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
```

On running the cell, I receive the following error even after factory resetting the runtime:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-225d47afe30d> in <module>()
----> 1 from radmc3dPy import *
      2 from radmc3dPy.image import *
      3 from radmc3dPy.analyze import *
      4 from radmc3dPy.natconst import *
      5 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'radmc3dPy'
```

Comment: radm3dPy is not part of your environment.  You need to acquire the library using something like pip.  Since, I am not familiar with Collab, I can't provide more help.

Answer (score 1):

you need to download and install the library before you can use it. I saw that there is a github for your package here: https://github.com/dullemond/radmc3d-2.0

in colab, you can install it with:

```
!git clone https://github.com/dullemond/radmc3d-2.0.git
%cd ./radmc3d-2.0/python/radmc3dPy/
!python setup.py install
%cd ~/../content
```

`!` and `%` are required.

The comand clones the desired directory from git, changes into the python directory, runs the setup of your package and changes your working directory back. Directly running the setup.py with the full path, did not work, hence changing the directory.